# Error when executing command <ng serve -o > in angular cli

Tags: angular-cli

```
Error: ./src/styles.css
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
    ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Error: 

    EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
        at C:\Users\user\myapp_angular\angular-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
        at C:\Users\user\myapp_angular\angular-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
        at C:\Users\user\myapp_angular\angular-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
        at context.callback (C:\Users\user\myapp_angular\angular-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
        at Object.loader (C:\Users\user\myapp_angular\angular-project\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:55:7)

Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

I'm getting this error when I try to run `ng serve -open`.

Answer (score 0):

**Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read**

Try to run the command as super user.

> **Linux:** sudo ng s -o

> **Windows:** Open CMD as administrator

Comment: when i created new ng folder in 'C:\Windows\System32\' path it worked. still error is shown when created in 'C:\Users\user' path.